# Is there a shrAddha ceremony as per agama? (if any)

Tags: tradition, tantra, sraddha, kaulam

We very well know about the shrAddha ceremony in our tradition which is done for the pitr/manes. It is towards their departed souls. Every year it is done during the pitru paksha.

However, apart from the traditional way of doing shrAddha is there a agamic/tantric way too?

if yes

how is it different from the usually prevalent procedure?

Comment: All the 16 Samskaras are described in Mahanirvana Tantra as regards how to perform them. So all of them can be performed as per Agamas too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a process of pitru shrAddha as per the tantra. But it is a restricted process hence not known open to general public but only the initiates or dikshitas.

**kaulashrAddha** is the annual ceremony performed for dIkShita pitR by the son who necessarily is also a dIkShita. Nevertheless, kaulashrAddha can be done by any **dIkShita** for any other diseased dIkShita. But performing the antyeShTi and maNDalamelana is a pre-requisite for performing the kaulashrAddha annually.

Unlike in the vaidika shrAddha, where the pitR-s ascend to the position of "vasu", "rudra" & "Aditya", in kaula, the dIkShita is raised to the state of **"mitresha", "ShaShTIsha" & "uDDIsha"** whose position is in the ultimate triangle of the shrIcakra.

gurupUjA or gurupAdukApUjA etc form part of one's nityAhnika as part of upAsanA.

reference is available in **trikUTArahasya** which is adapted in PKS (**parashurAma kalpa sutra**) in the sAdhAraNakrama

It is also possible that the guru doesnt have children... but his shiShya-s are eligible and entitled to perform his antyeShTi/maNDalamelana and thereafter the annual shrAddha ceremony. The only qualification for the disciples is that they are **pUrNAbhiShikta**-s. If a dIkShita has neither children nor shiShyas, his antyeShTi/maNDalamelana can still be performed by any other qualified dIkShita.

Similarly, in the case of the son being a dIkShita and the father being adIkShita, the son can and should still perform the antyeShTi/maNDalamelana by the mantraprabhAva of panchadashi after which the diseased pitR are assigned the dIkShAnAma from the mAnavaugha for eg.. gaganAnandanAtha / gaganAmbA.

Also, a dIkshita can also perform it for a deceased non dikshita who is not a relative, if he wishes.

Comment: If you can add the Parashurama Kalpa sutra chapter no. which you are quoting from, then the yellow banner will be removed.